# How to get a truly random number in C++

Tags: c++, random

I'm a beginner to C++ and I'm trying to figure out how to generate random numbers within a certain range. I have the following code, however when run it outputs the same random number 5 times. If I run this without the for loop several times, one after the other, it seems as though there is a pattern where the number chosen increases by 1 each second. Is there a way to get truly random numbers?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        srand(time(nullptr));

        const int maxValue = 6;
        const int minValue = 1;

        int randomNumber = (rand() % (maxValue - minValue + 1)) + minValue;
        cout << randomNumber << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I hope to output sequences such as 1,3,6,2,4, however I get sequences such as 1,1,1,1,1 and 3,3,3,3,3,3.

Comment: Truly random is highly unlikely. Pseudo random - you should not call `srand` in a loop.

Comment: You should call srand() only once, outside for loop. As it's now it's calling it several time with likely same value returned by time(), which will give same rand() results

Comment: The top link of duplicates explains why you keep getting the same number and then it changes.  The second link shows how to use the C++11 `<random>` to get better random numbers.

Comment: Valuable viewing: [rand() Considered Harmful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/goingnative-2013/rand-considered-harmful). Start watching to learn stuff, keep watching for the jokes (and to learn stuff).

Comment: I feel like step 1 would have been to do a search. Professors need to tell their students to not bother asking on SO unless they've taken the [tour], learned about the [mre], learned [ask], and looked at [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions?r=Saves_AllUserSaves). Then, don't ask the question.

Comment: The answer either already exists, or the student would be better served talking to the TA or professor. If you're not a student, then there's [the good book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?r=Saves_AllUserSaves). You won't learn C++ properly otherwise. It's just not a simple language, it evolves at a decent enough pace, and most of the free advice out there is complete trash.

Comment: The above is true. The simple fact is C++ has been active on Stack Overflow  since the beginning and over the past 15 years, pretty much every question a beginner is capable of asking (that's on topic and answerable at any rate) has been asked and answered. Probably a few times. Every few years the language is revised and there's a flurry of new questions, but otherwise new questions are the esoteric stuff that few if any beginners are banging their head against.